# How to search a file in resource monitor using powershell script

Tags: powershell, search

I would like to know which processes are using a particular file. This needs to be done through a powershell script. I opened resmon.exe using powershell. I would like to search that particular file in the.exe, but through ps script.

Could someone suggest something on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the openfiles command in Windows. To enable openfiles to query the local machine, you'll need to run the following command as administrator:

```
openfiles /local ON
```

After running that command, you'll need to restart your computer.

Once restarted, you can query your local machine for which process is using a specific file. Here's a snippet of code to get you on the right track:

```
$OpenFiles = openfiles /query /fo CSV /v | ForEach-Object {$line=$_; if($line -match '","'){$line}} | ConvertFrom-Csv

$OpenFiles | Where-Object -Property 'Open File (Path\executable)' -Like "*FileNameHere.txt*" | ft
```